# laravel URL::to('/') returns localhost as base url in deployment server

Tags: php, laravel, url, base-url

I have my application deployed in `http://www.nepathya.com`.

But when generating URL links as a part of email, base url is `localhost`.

```
public function handle(User $user)
{
    foreach($this->mail_details as $email=>$token) {
        $user_name = $user->getUserName($email);
        $url = URL::to('/').'/dmf/task?token='.$token;
        Mail::to($email)->send(new SendEmailMailable($url, $user_name));
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem to be a problem with other `servers`.

Also when I output value of `URL::to('/')` from elsewhere, it outputs correct base url, i.e. `http://www.nepathya.com`.

Comment: i have faced the same problem, i pointed on test domain to server later i changed it production domain in email it always send test domain link which makes me really crazy. even clearing cache too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change `'url'` value on **config/app.php**

```
'url' => 'http://www.nepathya.com',
```

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Sorry for this, I wanna to answer someone with explanation but my English is not pretty good, I will try answer with explanation next time

Comment: If you need to use a translator. All of your answers start with some version of "try" which you should avoid.

Comment: I will use translator next time to explain why/how the code is work

Answer (score 5):

If you have SSH access, I recommend going to `.env` file and modify `APP_URL` to your URL. Then run `php artisan config:cache`